# monit removed from CentOS8 and EPEL. Any replacement?

Tags: centos, rhel, monit

I upgraded to CentOS8 and noticed that monit removed from CentOS8 and EPEL. We have been using it to monitor processes.

I know I can build it but wondering why it was removed. Was it replaced with a better package?

Comment: It is back in EPEL now.

Answer (score 0):

We are not using CentOS, but Debian. IMHO, it is better not to package monit. Monit changed a lot recently (in 2019). Especially the version of monit packaged in Debian is known for lagging far behind the current version. Since it is quite easy to download and compile monit (the usual three-step `configure`, `make` and `make install`, and it does not depend on too many development packages), this should be the preferred method.